# Javascript Detecting collision on image with clear background

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a javascript game and I have an obstacle that when it touches the player's image, should take away a life. The problem is that I am currently detecting with the images' rectangles, and there are clear parts so it sometimes detects a collision when it doesn't look like the images are touching. I need a way to detect if the image is touching part of the image that isn't just clear background, like you make an outline of the non-clear part and check if the outlines collide. I don't know if this is possible to do with javascript, but let me know.

Comment: Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with more details. Adding your current and relevant code is a great place to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no good way of doing it fast. You see, if we do that, it will slow down much, as it says here : https://benjaminhorn.io/code/pixel-accurate-collision-detection-with-javascript-and-canvas/. You could make some smaller rectangles of different sizes, to help with more precise collisions.